# what are the parameters of configure method of tkinter/tk()

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="red")
```

Which parameters (***args***) are present in the `.configure` method.

Is it just `background` and if not how do I view them?

Answer (score 6):

The parameters for the `configure` method are different for each widget.

Tkinter's widgets have a concept of [options](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) like `color` and `size` and so on. Some of these options exist for every widget, but others don't. For example, the [`Entry` class](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) has a `validatecommand` option that most other widgets don't have.

The `configure` method lets you change the options of a widget, and the available parameters depend on the widget you're configuring. `Entry().configure(validatecommand=bool)` would be valid, but `Label().configure(validatecommand=bool)` wouldn't.

To find a complete list of valid parameters/options you can either look at [the documentation](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method) of the widget, or call the `configure` method without parameters, which will list all the available options:

```
>>> root.configure().keys()
dict_keys(['bd', 'borderwidth', 'class', 'menu', 'relief', 'screen', 'use', 'background', 'bg', 'colormap', 'container', 'cursor', 'height', 'highlightbackground', 'highlightcolor', 'highlightthickness', 'padx', 'pady', 'takefocus', 'visual', 'width'])
```

Comment: You might also mention that doing `root.configure()` without any arguments will give you a list of all of the configuration options and their current values (along with some additional information).

Comment: @BryanOakley Hmm, I don't think that's relevant information in a question asking about the function's parameters. Quite clearly the question is about _changing_ options, not about retrieving their current values.

Comment: The point is, if you don't know what the options are, the configure method will tell you the names of all of the options. The question was "what are parameters are present in configure method" and `root.configure()` answers that question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer above you may want to `print(tkinter.Tk().configure().keys())`, it took me couple minutes to figure out why it wasn't doing anything