# How to change every moment the background of the tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project, That I need for it to change every moment the background of the tkinter window. Now, I'm getting every moment a share screen from the computer who has the role of the server, and Now I need to set the background as the screenshot everymoment.
I have the next code,But I get an error while I run it.
If someone have other idea to do it, please tell me how.
It's important to say that in the code there are 2 diffrent images, but in the future code there will be only one image file(the screenshot file).

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
image2 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Proggramers Club\Your_image.png")

if(__name__ == "    __main__"):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.update()
    window_width = root.winfo_width()
    window_height = root.winfo_height()
    image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Proggramers Club\screenshot.png")
    resized_image = image.resize((window_width, window_height))
    photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    label = tk.Label(root, image = photo_image)
    label.pack()
    
    label.config(root, image = image2)
        
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Right now `image2` isn't a a `PhtotoImage`. It's a `Image.Image`. One way to fix it is to add `image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)` before the `label.config(root, image=image2)`

Comment: if you get error message then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see error message. Besides code can run correctly on our computers.

Answer (score 0):

### There are few issues with your code..

---

### 1.

The code as you wrote it won't run because there are few extra spaces in the `"    __main__"`:

```
if(__name__ == "    __main__"):
```

---

### 2.

You are getting an error because you are passing `root` to the [`config`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831943/what-are-the-parameters-of-configure-method-of-tkinter-tk) function.

```py
   label.config(root, image = image2)
```

You need to fix that:

```py
   label.config(image = image2)
```

---

### 3.

After you'll fix that, you would still get an error. That is because you passing an `Image` object in the `image` argument when it should be `ImageTk`.
You could fix that like so:

1. Create a function that takes `path, width, height` as argument and returns `ImageTk`.
2. Use that function to open all your images

The function:

```py
def get_tk_img(path, width, height):
    img = Image.open(path).resize((width, height))
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

And then:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.update()
    window_width = root.winfo_width()
    window_height = root.winfo_height()
    
    image = get_tk_img(r"Your path", window_width, window_height)
    image2 = get_tk_img(r"Your path", window_width, window_height)
    
    label = tk.Label(root, image = image)
    label.pack()
    label.config(image = image2)
        
    root.mainloop()
```

---

### * Note:

You will not see `image` because you are immediately replacing it with `image2`.

You can solve that by creating an `update` function that will change the image every some period of time:

```py
def update(lbl:tk.Label, imgs):
    def change_label(idx):
        lbl.config(image=imgs[idx])
        lbl.after(int(1000/30), change_label, (idx + 1) % len(imgs)) # 30 fps
        
    change_label(0)
```

And then:

```py
    image = get_tk_img("Your path", window_width, window_height)
    image2 = get_tk_img("Your path", window_width, window_height)
    
    label = tk.Label(root, image = image)
    label.pack()
    update(label, (image, image2))
        
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your second point is wrong. No `config()` is used in the code, and passing `root` as the first argument of `Label(...)` is valid.

Comment: @acw1668 I accidentally copied the wrong line.. Thanks for bringing this to my attention :)